# gather on first two rows

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape2

I have some poorly formatted data that I must work with.  It contains two identifiers in the first two rows, followed by the data.  The data looks like:

```
     V1       V2       V3
1  Date 12/16/18 12/17/18
2 Equip        a        b
3    x1        1        2
4    x2        3        4
5    x3        5        6
```

I want to `gather` the data to make it tidy, but gathering only works when you have single column names. I've tried looking at spreading as well. The only solutions I've come up with are very hacky and don't feel right. Is there an elegant way to deal with this?

Here's what I want:

```
      Date Equip metric value
1 12/16/18     a     x1     1
2 12/16/18     a     x2     3
3 12/16/18     a     x3     5
4 12/17/18     b     x1     2
5 12/17/18     b     x2     4
6 12/17/18     b     x3     6
```

This approach gets me close, but I don't know how to deal with the poor formatting (no header, no row names). It should be easy to `gather` if the formatting was proper.

```
> as.data.frame(t(df))
         V1    V2 V3 V4 V5
V1     Date Equip x1 x2 x3
V2 12/16/18     a  1  3  5
V3 12/17/18     b  2  4  6
```

And here's the `dput`

```
structure(list(V1 = c("Date", "Equip", "x1", "x2", "x3"), V2 = c("12/16/18", 
"a", "1", "3", "5"), V3 = c("12/17/18", "b", "2", "4", "6")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for posting a nicely reproducible question. Here's some gentle `tidyr`/`dplyr` massaging.

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    gather(key = measure, value = value, -V1) %>%
    spread(key = V1, value = value) %>%
    dplyr::select(-measure) %>%
    gather(key = metric, value = value, x1:x3) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(Date, Equip, metric)
#>       Date Equip metric value
#> 1 12/16/18     a     x1     1
#> 2 12/16/18     a     x2     3
#> 3 12/16/18     a     x3     5
#> 4 12/17/18     b     x1     2
#> 5 12/17/18     b     x2     4
#> 6 12/17/18     b     x3     6
```

**Updated for `tidyr` v1.0.0:**

This is just a little bit cleaner syntax with the `pivot` functions.

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -V1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = V1) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = matches("x\\d"), names_to = "metric") %>%
  dplyr::select(-name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using `reshape`

```
library(reshape)
row.names(df) = df$V1
df$V1 = NULL
df = melt(data.frame(t(df)),id.var = c('Date','Equip'))
df[order(df$Date),]
      Date Equip variable value
1 12/16/18     a       x1     1
3 12/16/18     a       x2     3
5 12/16/18     a       x3     5
2 12/17/18     b       x1     2
4 12/17/18     b       x2     4
6 12/17/18     b       x3     6
```

Comment: Or the data.table version of the same thing: `melt(setnames(transpose(df[, -1]), df[[1]]), id = c("Date", "Equip"))` (just using `transpose` and `setnames`; otherwise the same).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way starting from your approach using `t()`. We can replace the headers from the first row and then drop the first row, allowing just a single `gather` which might be more intuitive.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("Date", "Equip", "x1", "x2", "x3"), V2 = c(
  "12/16/18",
  "a", "1", "3", "5"
), V3 = c("12/17/18", "b", "2", "4", "6")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c(
  "V1",
  "V2", "V3"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df %>%
  t() %>%
  `colnames<-`(.[1, ]) %>%
  `[`(-1, ) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  gather("metric", "value", x1:x3) %>%
  arrange(Date, Equip, metric)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   Date     Equip metric value
#>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 12/16/18 a     x1     1    
#> 2 12/16/18 a     x2     3    
#> 3 12/16/18 a     x3     5    
#> 4 12/17/18 b     x1     2    
#> 5 12/17/18 b     x2     4    
#> 6 12/17/18 b     x3     6
```

Created on 2018-04-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).